# Initializing a class template that implements itself in the constructor

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I am rather new to using templates and the STL in general. Still doing my research but have come across a class that I am having a hard time understanding. I found a [TreeNode implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47395/tree-template-class-implementation-for-c) that I would like to tinker with but I am having trouble initializing the object.

In the constructor, one of the parameters is a reference to itself. But how the heck do you pass a reference to a parent node if it's never been created?

```
TreeNode(TreeNode<T>* parent, T data);
```

Any direction would be nice. I would like to learn more about this construct.

Thanks

Comment: The first parameter seems to be a pointer to the parent node.  I presume you have to give `nullptr` for the tree's root.

Comment: @nickie I gave that a whirl and it worked. Let me just do my walk of shame now...

Comment: Hehe, cheers... :-)

Comment: @nickie You should make your comment into an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the first parameter is a pointer to the parent node.  (Not only because the parameter's name is `parent`, but also because of how it's used in the [linked implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47395/tree-template-class-implementation-for-c), e.g., see method `addChild` which sets this parameter to `this`.)

Therefore, constructing the tree's root should have a `nullptr` in the place of the parent.

```
TreeNode<int>* root = new TreeNode<int>(nullptr, 42);
```

Subsequently, other nodes can be added as children of existing nodes:

```
TreeNode<int>* leftChild = new TreeNode<int>(root, 17);
TreeNode<int>* rightChild = new TreeNode<int>(root, 37);
TreeNode<int>* rightGrandChild = new TreeNode<int>(rightChild, 64);
```

producing the tree:

[image: tree]

BTW, the linked implementation provides methods `getChild` and `addChild` for getting/adding children of/to existing nodes.  Using these two, the above tree can be constructed as follows:

```
TreeNode<int>* root = new TreeNode<int>(nullptr, 42);
root->addChild(17);
root->addChild(37);
root->getChild(1)->addChild(64);   // add to root's child[1]
```

IMHO, it seems to be missing a way to construct the root's tree without exposing the underlying implementation (i.e., the class constructor that takes the pointer to the parent node).  I'd suggest making the constructor private and adding a static method:

```
template <class T>
static TreeNode<T>* TreeNode<T>::makeRoot (const T& data) {
  return new TreeNode<T>(nullptr, data);
}
```

Using this, the above tree could be constructed using TreeNode as an ADT:

```
TreeNode<int>* root = TreeNode<int>::makeRoot(42);
root->addChild(17);
root->addChild(37);
root->getChild(1)->addChild(64);   // add to root's child[1]
```